# Custom Sorting in Meteor MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a Meteor Publication which returns a set of products from a collection. Each document contains a field called 'grade' for which we have assigned a string value of 'S', 'A', 'B', 'C', or 'D'. Each Grade tier represents a more broad condition of an item where 'S' is the best possible condition, 'A' is the next best, then 'B', and so on...

When I return the collection, I want to sort by the grade. Obviously it would not make any sense for MongoDB to have S-Grade products appear first on the list by default, because A, B, C, and D all come before S in standard alphabetical sorting.

Is there a way to set up custom sorting so that I can allow Grade-S items to appear at the top of the list of results during a sort, but also allowing A, B, C, and D to appear following in their proper order?

Comment: I don't think that mongodb offers a custom comparator, and I expect the performance of such operation would be poor anyway. I suggest that you add a numeric grade that is associated to the grade (you can even not store the string at all and use it as a pseudo-enumerable type that maps the numeric value to a string for display purposes). This will allow you to sort, and do so efficiently using an index.

Comment: Ah, so something like
`{grade: {value: 1, display: 'S'}}`
... and then just sort by the _value_, but show the _display_ instead?
Makes perfect sense! I think that should probably work.

I saw some older posts that said mongodb does not support this type of sorting (yet), but again they were old posts and I was not sure if that still applied.

Anyways, that should work great, thank you!
If it was an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that mongodb offers a custom comparator for sorting, and I expect the performance of such operation would be poor anyway.

The best option is to use a numeric field for sorting purposes and, if needed, add the string for display purposes (and keep them in sync during document updates etc.).

You can avoid storing the string if you don't strictly need it in the database, and map the numeric value to the string whenever it needs to be displayed. Meteor lets you specify a [`transform`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html) in a query to a collection, and the platform will do the rest for you.